# Select from join tables with linq

Tags: linq

I have three tables:

1- Table `Car_Types`

```
 _____________________
|   Id  |    Name    |
|____________________|
|   1   |  Pickup    |   
|   2   |  Sedan     |
|   3   |  Minivan   | 
|   4   |   SUV      |
|____________________|
```

2 - Table `Car_Options`

```
_________________________________________________
|   Id  |    Car_Type_Id     |      Company_Id   |
_________________________________________________|
|   1   |          1         |       Null        |
|   2   |          2         |       Null        |
|   3   |          3         |       Null        |
|   4   |          4         |       Null        |
|   5   |          1         |         1         |
|   6   |          2         |         1         |
|________________________________________________|
```

3 - Table companies which is similar the table car_types

So I want to select using `linq` all the `car_options` and the thing is: The query has a `Company_Id X` so I want all the `car_options` (4) with `Company_Id == X` but if there isn’t a `car_option` whit `company_id == x` for one of the `car_type_ids` then I want that `car_option` with that `car_type_id` and `company_id==null`. I think that what I need is to make a join but I don’t know how to do that.

So if the company_id was 1 the results i want would be:

```
_________________________________________________
|   Id  |    Car_Type_Id     |      Company_Id   |
_________________________________________________|
|   5   |          1         |        1          |
|   6   |          2         |        1          |
|   3   |          3         |       Null        |
|   4   |          4         |       Null        |
|________________________________________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little convoluted - but let's start here.

You want to find everything that has a company_ID x so you start with a simple linq query:

```
car_options.Where(c => c.Company_Id == X);
```

You then want to also grab any that doesn't have a Company_Id but that has a car_type_id that matches x...so add to your query

```
car_options.Where(c => c.Company_Id == X || (c.Company_Id == null && c.car_type_id == x))
```

Then you only want to take the ones with the company id that matches, if it exists.  So, group them by company id, order the groups descending by companyID, so if there are ones that have the (non-null) company ID they will be first (otherwise there is only one group - null company ids)

```
car_options.Where(c => c.Company_Id == X || (c.Company_Id == null && c.car_type_id == x))
    .GroupBy(c => c.Company_ID)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns an IGrouping which you can use the same as an IEnumerable (it will just have a key, which could be handy if you want to check if you are looking at a null company id or one that matches x.

Edit based on more clear requirements:

```
car_options.GroupBy(c => c.car_type_id)
    .Select(g => g.Where(c => c.Company_ID == X || c.Company_Id == null)
                      .OrderByDescending(c => c.Company_ID)
                      .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added an example of what I am looking for in order to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: Oh - that makes more sense!  Group by car_Type_Id (because you want one of each), select the first one from that group that has a company_ID of x, and if that doesn't exist get the first one with a null company id.  I'll add a code edit in my answer